# How to display cms block in product page if some attribute is set to yes

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, blocks, cms

I want to display cms block if product has the attribute set to yes. A product may have multiple attributes set to yes, and may display multiple cms blocks. Attribute label text will be a BlockId. It may also be another proposed method. How do I see it:

```
    <?php 
    if(($_product->getAttributeText('*') == "yes")){
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID(getAttributeText())->tohtml(); 
   }
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes, either you can make the above method or use another method like create array on phtml based on that one you can use that things.

Comment: My method does not work, this is not the correct code

Answer (score 1):

you need to try this code.

```
<?php
    if(($_product->getYourCustomattribute()))
    {
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID('Your_Block_Id')->tohtml(); 
    }
?>
```